# Adding a label to outgoing mail, Gmail also moves it to the inbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I have a filter which adds a label, applied to both `from:` and `to:` addresses.

When I compose a new mail (not reply) matched by that filter the label is correctly applied, but the mail also ends up in the inbox.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could try creating a separate filter, where you specify that mail with you as the sender skips the inbox.